# A replacement for std::bind2nd

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, bind2nd

I have a `foo` which is a `std::vector<int>`. It represents the "edge" values for a set of ranges.

For example, if `foo` is {1, 3, 5, 7, 11} then the ranges are 1-3, 3-5, 5-7, 7-11. Significantly for me, this equates to 4 periods. Note that each period includes the first number in a range, and not the last one. So in my example, 8 appears in the 3rd (zero-based) period. 7 also appears in the 3rd period. 11 and above doesn't appear anywhere. 2 appears in the 0th period.

Given a `bar` which is an `int`, I use

```
std::find_if(
    foo.begin(),
    foo.end(),
    std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(), bar)
) - foo().begin() - 1;
```

to give me the period that should contain `bar`.

My problem: `std::bind2nd` is deprecated so I ought to refactor. What is the equivalent statement using updated functions? `std::bind` doesn't "drop in" in the obvious way.

Comment: BTW, `std::distance(foo.begin(), std::lower_bound(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar)) - 1;` seems more appropriate here.

Comment: Was the `c++11` tag a requirement, or was it just a good fit when the question was asked? Anyway, if you're now actually fine with later versions, you could "tag it up" to allow @TemplateRex's answer to be fully impedance-matched. :) (See comments there.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C++11, you can use `std::bind`; it just isn't as obvious how to use it:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::find_if(
    foo.begin(),
    foo.end(),
    // create a unary function object that invokes greater<int>::operator()
    // with the single parameter passed as the first argument and `bar` 
    // passed as the second argument
    std::bind(std::greater<int>(), _1, bar)
) - foo().begin() - 1;
```

The key is the use of the placeholder argument, which are declared in the `std::placeholders` namespace. `std::bind` returns a function object that takes some number of parameters when it is invoked. The placeholders used inside the call to `std::bind` show how the arguments provided when the resulting object is invoked map to the argument list to the callable that you're binding to. So, for instance:

```
auto op1 = std::bind(std::greater<int>(), _1, bar);
op1(5); // equivalent to std::greater<int>()(5, bar)

auto op2 = std::bind(std::greater<int>(), bar, _1);
op2(5); // equivalent to std::greater<int>()(bar, 5)

auto op3 = std::bind(std::greater<int>(), _2, _1);
op3(5, bar); // equivalent to std::greater<int>()(bar, 5)

auto op4 = std::bind(std::greater<int>(), _1, _2);
op4(5, bar); // equivalent to std::greater<int>()(5, bar)
```

Answer (score 16):

What about going straight from Stone Age (`bind2nd`) to the Iron Age with a C++14 generic lambda, bypassing the Bronze Age (`bind`)?

```
std::find_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [&](auto const& elem) { 
    return elem > bar; 
});
```

And if the input is sorted

```
std::lower_bound(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar);
```

Lambdas read much easier and are also easier to inline than `std::bind` expresions. See e.g. [**Lavevej's CppCon 2015**](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E66E02DC83EFB165!330&authkey=!AKKxyO0eYikyPT8&ithint=file,pptx) talk.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the easiest to read solution, but the question's tags only included C++11.

Comment: @JasonR my philosophy is to show how I would code it, unless they claim that they really can't use C++14, and even then I'd show it if the savings are  large enough :) The Q&A is not just for the OP, but for the public at large. But I upvoted your `bind` answer :)

Comment: Fair enough; that makes sense. +1.

Comment: @JasonR btw, Scott Meyers even had a talk a while ago called "burying bind"

Answer (score 7):

`bind` version would be:

```
bind(std::greater<int>(), placeholders::_1, bar)
```

but I think, it is more encouraged to use lambdas, as in:

```
[bar](const int a){return bar < a;}
```

It is also encouraged to use overloaded functions `begin/end` instead of method calls. so it would be like:

```
find_if(begin(foo), end(foo), [bar](const int a){return bar < a;})
```

Comment: What is `placeholders::_1`?

Comment: Could you be an angel and put the whole thing together? ;-)

Comment: @P45Imminent literally _placeholders_; see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/placeholders/?kw=placeholders)